# How to find out the out the lowest date for each integration_id group where the name column is approved?

Tags: postgresql

```
id | integration_id | date | name
(1, 1, 2021-04-14 18:04:18.167+05:30, approved)
(2, 1, 2021-04-15 18:04:18.167+05:30, approved)
(3, 2, 2021-04-16 18:04:18.167+05:30, not approved)
(4, 2, 2021-04-17 18:04:18.167+05:30, approved)
```

If there are multiple integration_ids like these and we need to choose only the approved rows, how do I write a query to fetch the minimum date rows from each integration id group in postgresql.

```
id | integration_id | date | name
(1, 1, 2021-04-14 18:04:18.167+05:30, approved)
(4, 2, 2021-04-17 18:04:18.167+05:30, approved)
```

This should be my final answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Postgres, `DISTINCT ON` comes in handy here:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (integration_id) *
FROM yourTable
WHERE name = 'approved'
ORDER BY integration_id, date;
```

Comment: ok, thanks will do. I had one more question - we always need to also order by the distinct on field, right? Do you know why?

Comment: @krtchen Good question.  Whatever columns appear in the `(...)` after `DISTINCT ON` must also appear, in that order, in the `ORDER BY` clause.  This is the ordering logic that determines _which_ distinct record per `integration_id` group gets chosen for the result set.